how a class call with this format?
hi I clone a php library from github but xampp get this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\browser\tests\BrowserTest.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\browser\tests\BrowserTest.php on line 12
I not exper but someone can help to me

when you manually manage your code base its your responsibility to include library into your code, so you either forgot or count with autoloader which is not configured.

@PaulT. we souldn't really use aggregator questions as dupe targets. It's confusing for people and bad for SEO.
